# Fatal error: index out of range (swift xcode)

Tags: swift, xcode

I keep getting an index out of range error. I am trying to loop through an array and return the value.

```
override func countNeighbors(grid: [[Character?]], column x: Int, row y: Int) -> Int {
    var sum = 0
    for k in 1...2{
        for l in 1...2 {
            sum += getAlive(grid, column: x - 1 + l, row: y - 1 + l)

        }
    }
    return sum - getAlive(grid, column: x, row: y)
}
```

Comment: whats getting passed as the grid variable?

Comment: You should add some precisions to your post like what arguments you are passing the function. The line where the exception occurs. Or some more code.

Answer (score 0):

You most probably have messed up with  the columns/rows. You should check if you did not swap the 2. It seems that the exception come from your `getAlive` function so if you can post it, we might be able to help you more than this.

Answer (score 0):

'Index out of range means that an array subscript has gone outside the actual size of the array. For example, if your array has 2 elements, they would be represented like:
'arrayVariable[0]' and 'arrayVariable[1]'

A common array mistake is to forget that the array is 0-based, and attempt to access the values with subscripts starting with 1. In this example, that would cause an attempt to access 'arrayVariable[2]', which would be past the end of the array, causing an 'index out of range' message.

Check your values to ensure you're not going past the end of the array.